# Selenium - auto completion (prediction text)

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I am new to selenium web driver.

When I try to auto-complete a particular text and select an option from the prediction text list as given below, it selects the appropriate option.

The problem is after the phrase gets populated in the text box, the prediction text list is displayed again, due to which it is unable to perform the next step.

I am using xpath to select the option from the prediction text list:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//div[@class='mui-pt-bd']//li[2]")).click();
```

Please let me know what I can do regarding this.

Comment: Due to which it is unable to perform the next step.  What is the next step you are doing? can you let us know?

Answer (score 0):

Try adding some synchronization code to wait for the prediction list. After that call the click method. See http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp

Answer (score 0):

First, make sure there are no trailing spaces for the prediction text that you chose by clicking from the list. If there are, it might trigger the prediction text list to open up again. 
If this not the case, the only thing that I can think of is, clicking elsewhere within the same frame/form so that the prediction text list gets closed. 
Another thought is that, after choosing one item, the usually expected behavior is for the drop-down to close. If that is not happening manually, then, you might want to make sure it is not a bug with the Application itself.